# how to authenticate acc client against remote realm

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, jaas

Hi I need to authenticate a swing client app to a realm existing in a remote glassfish 3. How can I do that?  I guess it could be possible if I made the the swing app, an acc client.. I have tried to find anything but the documentation doesn't says much and there are no examples

Does anyone know a tutorial or how to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to mention how your swing client is going to talk to the server. EJB? REST? ...

Comment: EJB.. after authenticate